# How can I get a selected text from another application?

Tags: c++, winapi

I trie to get a selected text from another application without use the clipboard. I have find the way to have the HWND from the active application but when I use EM_GETSELTEXT they are no text in the buffer.

```
 char* shortcut::getSelectedText(){
  POINT mouse;
  if (GetCursorPos(&mouse)){
  HWND window = WindowFromPoint(mouse);//get the HWND from the active application
    if (window != nullptr){
        char* buffer = new char[100];
        SendMessage(window , EM_GETSELTEXT, 0, LPARAM(buffer));
        return buffer;  
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
  }
  else{
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please rename-translate variables  `racourci`, `souri` and `fenetre` to English? Your code looks a little obfuscated.

Comment: The HWND is a Rich Edit box, right?

Comment: `EM_GETSELTEXT` is in the `WM_USER+x` range of messages. The system does not provide automatic marshaling of pointers for messages in that range. You'll have to allocate memory in the target process, or use one of the standard Windows messages (e.g. `WM_GETTEXT`). Of course, the Right Thing™ to do is to go with [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Unless you are happy with your application randomly failing.